# Django: Cannot assign “<Booking: loader2>”: “Booking.b_price” must be a “Loader_post” instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

### hi am working on a project where driver add price to the user post...now user can accept and reject the offer ....when the user accepts offer it do booking but after submitting the form it gives error

this is my models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    post =  models.ForeignKey(Loader_post, 
     related_name='b_price',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pay = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=30 ,default='')
```

this is my views.py

```
class booking_approve(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_class = forms.booking_form
    model = Booking
    template_name = "confirm_booking.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("Loader:post")

def form_valid(self, form,*args, **kwargs):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    bk = form.save(commit=False)
    bk.user = self.request.user
    bk.post = booking
    bk.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

### this is my urls.py

```
path('confirm_booking/<int:pk>/booking',views.booking_approve.as_view(), name="booking_approve"),
```

this is my html page

```
{% for loader_post in request.user.Loader.all %}
{% for price in loader_post.prices.all %}
    <img src="{{loader_post.image_of_load.url }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%; height: 25%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; ">
    <h4><b>Post id : {{loader_post.id }}</b></h4>
    <p>Driver offer : <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{price.driver_price }}</p>
    <p>Offer by : {{price.driver_name }}</p>
    <a style="margin-right:20px;" href="{% url 'Loader:booking_remove' pk=loader_post.pk %}"><i 
     class="fa fa-times fa-4x" style="color: red;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="{% url 'Loader:booking_approve' pk=loader_post.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa- 
         4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
```

### this is the error in my views

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

With:

```
booking = get_object_or_404(Loader_post, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Because previously you were trying to assign a booking object to another booking object. Instead, it should be `Loader_post` object. Also I can see here, you are sending the `Loader_post`'s primary key as url argument.